# Diagnosing Kafka Connection Problems

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, apache-kafka, docker-swarm

I have tried to build as much diagnostics into my Kafka connection setup as possible, but it still leads to mystery problems. In particular, the first thing I do is use the Kafka Admin Client to get the clusterId, because if this operation fails, nothing else is likely to succeed.

```
def getKafkaClusterId(describeClusterResult: DescribeClusterResult): Try[String] = {
  try {
    val clusterId = describeClusterResult.clusterId().get(futureTimeout.length / 2, futureTimeout.unit)
    Success(clusterId)
  } catch {
    case cause: Exception =>
      Failure(cause)
  }
}
```

In testing this usually works, and everything is fine. It generally only fails when the endpoint is not reachable somehow. It fails because the future times out, so I have no other diagnostics to go by. To test these problems, I usually telnet to the endpoint, for example

```
$ telnet blah 9094
Trying blah...
Connected to blah.
Escape character is '^]'.


Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Generally if I can telnet to a Kafka broker, I can connect to Kafka from my server. So my questions are:

1. What does it mean if I can reach the Kafka brokers via telnet, but I cannot connect via the Kafka Admin Client
2. What other diagnostic techniques are there to troubleshoot Kafka broker connection problems?

In this particular case, I am running Kafka on AWS, via a Docker Swarm, and trying to figure out why my server cannot connect successfully. I can see in the broker logs when I try to telnet in, so I know the brokers are reachable. But when my server tries to connect to any of 3 brokers, the logs are completely silent.

Comment: Is it a problem with your Kafka advertised hostname?

Comment: Yes, eventually I discovered that is the problem. I consider it a defect in Kafka.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good article that explains the steps that happens when you first connect to a Kafka broker

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/72429/how-kafka-producer-work-internally.html

If you can telnet to the bootstrap server then it is listening for client connections and requests.

However clients don't know which real brokers are the leaders for each of the partitions of a topic so the first request they always send to a bootstrap server is a metadata request to get a full list of all the topic metadata. The client uses the metadata response from the bootstrap server to know where it can then make new connections to each of Kafka brokers with the active leaders for each topic partition of the topic you are trying to produce to.

That is where your misconfigured broker problem comes into play. When you misconfigure the advertised.listener port the results of the first metadata request are redirecting the client to connect to unreachable IP addresses or hostnames. It's that second connection that is timing out, not the first one on the port you are telnet'ing into.

Another way to think of it is that you have to configure a Kafka server to work properly as both a bootstrap server and a regular pub/sub message broker since it provides both services to clients. Yours are configured correctly as a pub/sub server but incorrectly as a bootstrap server because the internal and external ip addresses are different in AWS (also in docker containers or behind a NAT or a proxy).

It might seem counter intuitive in small clusters where your bootstrap servers are often the same brokers that the client is eventually connecting to but it is actually a very helpful architectural design that allow kafka to scale and to failover seamlessly without needing to provide a static list of 20 or more brokers on your bootstrap server list, or maintain extra load balancers and health checks to know onto which broker to redirect the client requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not configure listeners and advertised.listeners correctly, basically Kafka just does not listen. Even though telnet is listening on the ports you've configured, the Kafka Client Library silently fails.

I consider this a defect in the Kafka design which leads to unnecessary confusion.

Comment: It's true that if you do not configure Kafka correctly it does not work. Fortunately this setup is a one time event and can be automated. You can even use one of several Kafka-as-a-Service SaaS providers and never have to bother with the setup yourself.

Comment: Excellent idea, or we might use Kinesis. Maybe we can just pay someone to set it up for us in AWS initiall.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing [Anand Immannavar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584082/anand-immannavar)'s answer from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58029656/cant-connect-spring-application-to-debezium-kafka/61789797):

Along with **ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME**, You need to add **ADVERTISED_LISTENERS** to container environment.

ADVERTISED_LISTENERS - Broker will register this value in zookeeper and when the external world wants to connect to your Kafka Cluster they can connect over the network which you provide in ADVERTISED_LISTENERS property.

example:

```
environment:
    - ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=<Host IP>
    - ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://<Host IP>:9092
```