# Can't connect spring application to debezium kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, spring-kafka, debezium

I'm trying to connect my spring application to the debezium/kafka:0.10 but no success. Originally the app uses wurstmeister/kafka image but now I'm introducing a new functionality with debezium and want to use only one kafka image for the both. I can't connect neither app to debezium kafka or debezium to wurstmeister kafka. Do someone knows is it possible to use only one image for both? Any ideas are welcome :)

The problem is that the app is not able to create the topic's into debezium  container. And also debezium is not able to work with wurstmeister kafka image.

```
ERROR 18864 --- [           main] o.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin  : Could not configure topics

org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Timed out waiting to get existing topics; nested exception is java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaAdmin.lambda$checkPartitions$2(KafkaAdmin.java:235) ~[spring-kafka-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1336) ~[na:na]
```

```
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: debezium/zookeeper:0.10
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
      - 2888:2888
      - 3888:3888
  kafka:
    image: debezium/kafka:0.10
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    links:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
      - ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=10.0.75.1
  connect:
    image: debezium/connect:0.10
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    links:
      - kafka
      - mysql
    environment:
      - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
      - GROUP_ID=1
      - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
      - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
      - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kafka Cannot Configure Topics on Application Startup, but Later Can Communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953078/kafka-cannot-configure-topics-on-application-startup-but-later-can-communicate)

Comment: Totally different

Comment: Then might I suggest you provide more details about your environment, code, and configuration?  You've tried two different images with the same outcome.  It's hard to diagnose the underlying problem without more details.

Comment: Sounds like you misconfigured `ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME` property. Debezium works with any Kafka container

Comment: ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME  -> 172.0.0.1:9092 if someone has a example configuration with debezium working with different kafka than debezium/kafka is welcome

Answer (score 1):

Along with **ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME**, You need to add **ADVERTISED_LISTENERS** to container environment.

ADVERTISED_LISTENERS - Broker will register this value in zookeeper and when the external world wants to connect to your Kafka Cluster they can connect over the network which you provide in ADVERTISED_LISTENERS property.

example:

```
environment:
    - ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=<Host IP>
    - ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://<Host IP>:9092
```